# How to efficiently query complex hierarchy on MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Let's say you have two collections: CollectionA and CollectionB.

In CollectionA you have a document model like this

```
_id
childs{
   kind
   position
   childA
   childB
}
```

With `childA` being a reference to a document in the CollectionA, and `childB` being a reference to a document in CollectionB

In CollectionB you have a document model like this

```
_id
propertyA
propertyB
```

What I've done in Node.Js is a recursive function like in this pseudocode

```
function getProperties(id){
    let properties = [];
    if(id) {
        let document = collectionB.findOne(id);
        if(document && document.childs) {
            for(let child of document.childs) {
                if(child.childB){
                    properties = properties.concat(getProperties(child.childB)):
                }
                if(child.childA){
                    let documentA = collectionA.findOne(child.childA);
                    if(documentA){
                        properties.push(documentA.prpertyA);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return properties;
}
```

However, as childs grows, the time to get all the properties from the hierarchy grows as well, sometimes leading to a minute of waiting time (or even timeouts in some cases!). So, how can I improve this, maybe using some mongodb native functions? I'm already using DataLoader inside the `findOne` functions, which helped but not as much as I thought.

Answer (score 1):

You can use aggregate to create complex queries in a simple way.

For your example, you have two collections: 
*Collection A*, 
*Collection B*

Your base collection is B, so we can create an aggregate pipeline from collection B

```
db.collectionB.aggregate([
{
    $match: { _id: id } //
},
{
    $lookup:
    {
        from: 'collectionB',
        localField: '_id',
        foreignField: 'childB',
        as: 'childBobj'
    }
}
{
    $lookup:
    {
        from: 'collectionA',
        localField: '_id',
        foreignField: 'childA',
        as: 'childAobj'
    }
}
])
```

The query is not completely satisify your goal, Please make changes accordingly.

And I highly reccommended you to take a look at [db.collection.aggregate](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/)

And even you can use indexing to make this query execution time faster.

Happy coding!.

Comment: Yes, after many researches I come up with a similar solution, but instead I'm using the `$graphLookup` operator, which seems better then plain lookup since it can retrieve document in a recursive way (which ultimately is what I want) :)
[https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/graphLookup/](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/graphLookup/)